# Database First Entity.Add(EntityObject WithAutoIncrementing Key)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, auto-increment, objectcontext

I am using Entity-Framework Database First , I have my ObjectContext.Entity bound to a binding source which in turn is bound to my winforms controls. When I change text on my winforms controls it populates down to Current ObjectContext.Entity - I click CreateCopy  - to copy the current ObjectContext.Entity , now when I try to Add the new object - it fails, I tried simply to add the current object and it failed with the duplicate key error (of course), if I set the Key (it is ID type int, auto increment) to 0  it does not add it to the ObjextContext.EntitySet , so I said ok I will just save changes as well and see what happens - but it is not in the context so how can it save it ?? Neither does it save it. So what could I be doing wrong.

This is my CreateCopy Code

```
BrandItem = new BRAND();                    
BrandItem = TestBrand(BrandItem);// just a test case BrandItem ID, Name Columns
this.ContextEntities.BRAND.AddObject(BrandItem); // It is not adding anything here but I sure would like it to;
```

I have also tried

```
BrandItem = (ObjectContext.BRAND)bsBrand.Current; // This fails with a non-unique key error , if I change the ID to 0 it still does not work
```

Does any one know how to do this with an AutoIncrementing ID key and Entity Framework Database First ??

Comment: Post implementation of `TestBrand` method. How you created copy of your entity using C#?

Comment: Here is the TestBrand..
What I discovered today is that if I put the savechanges method in my CreateCopy code - it adds to the Database.
I do not want the functionality to do that; until the user clicks save or cancel ; I need it to be part of the ObjectContext so that it appears in the databound winforms controls until such time as they click save or cancel. ContextEntities is a property of the Form. I do not give it an .ID
                `private BRAND TestBrand(BRAND BrandItem)
  {BrandItem.BrandName = "NEW BRAND";
  BrandItem.Pcode = 2;
  return BrandItem;   
  }`

Comment: COPY Existing Entity:
BrandItem = (SortEDEF.BRAND)bsBrand.Current;

Comment: if I use this BRAND `BrandItem = this.ContextEntities.CreateObject<BRAND>();`
The ID gets set to 0 and
Weirdly My CreateCopy click event code runs twice, and two objects get added to the database.